# PHP include directory error cache

Tags: php, html

Error on my remote server:

```
"Warning: include_once(../_includes/check_login_status.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/60/10824160/html/index.php on line 1"
```

Hey guys, I'm trying to get all these directory errors fixed. Basically, I moved entire website folder to a different computer, and now my php include functions are trying to find `"/home/content/60/10824160/html/index.php"` which doesn't exist on this computer.

My `index.php` is in `Desktop/www/`  and my `check_login_status` is in `Desktop/www/_includes/`

I tried using the php cache function but do not understand. What do I need to do?

Comment: If the path does not exist why are you looking there?

Comment: Which path? I'm sorry I am a beginner

Comment: Why does the code look in `/home/**` when it's located in `~/Desktop/www`? My guess is the path is hardcoded in your php file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Remove or correct your `include_once` - it is the only one solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/_includes/check_login_status.php");
```

also make sure your file/directory names are correct.